# How to Autoscroll horizontal listview android

Tags: android

I have used a horizontal listView.I get the code from https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView.The list scrolls fine.Now i want that the list should also scroll automatically.But Not able to do so.Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check this link for what u want, i think exact result for this one. Hope You Don't Forget to give upvote.

https://github.com/blessenm/AndroidAutoScrollListView